# php preg_replace all the link with #

Tags: php, preg-replace

there are more words in a text, some are english, some are latins, now, how to use  `preg_replace`, broken all the links with `#`? make something like:

`<a href="#next">flow to the next</a>` => `flow to the next` ? (only broken the links with `#` in a long text.

Thanks.

not work for this.

```
$new = preg_replace('/<a(?:.*?)(href="#)(?:.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/is', '$2', $old); 
// this will also broken other links...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$old = '<a href="#next">flow to the next</a> ';
$new = preg_replace('/(<a href="\#.*?">)(.*?)<\/a>/is', '$2', $old); 
echo $new;
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/a9f88.php)