# Text process and insert it to database

Tags: php, domdocument

I grabbed a html code and inserted it into my database.

It looks like this, but I don't need this exactly. I need the same html code but I want all links inside it to have href="#" and I don't know exactly how can I do this.

```
<div id="olpDivId"> <span class="olpCondLink" ><a class="buyAction olpBlueLink" href="/gp/offer-listing/B002YDZSQM/ref=dp_olp_new/192-2317768-5155903?ie=UTF8&condition=new">4&nbsp;new</a>&nbsp;from&nbsp;<span class="price">$164.99</span></span> <span class="olpCondLink" ><a class="buyAction olpBlueLink" href="/gp/offer-listing/B002YDZSQM/ref=dp_olp_used/192-2317768-5155903?ie=UTF8&condition=used">18&nbsp;used</a>&nbsp;from&nbsp;<span class="price">$80.00</span></span> <span class="olpCondLink" ><a class="buyAction olpBlueLink" href="/gp/offer-listing/B002YDZSQM/ref=dp_olp_refurbished/192-2317768-5155903?ie=UTF8&condition=refurbished">6&nbsp;refurbished</a>&nbsp;from&nbsp;<span class="price">$124.95</span></span> </div>
```

Do I made myself clear about what I am trying to do?

Best regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php preg\_replace all the link with #](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791248/php-preg-replace-all-the-link-with)

Comment: Use PHP+DomDocument which is the right tool for extracting information from HTML. [PHP DOMDocument : how to select all links under a specific tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514903/php-domdocument-how-to-select-all-links-under-a-specific-tag)

Comment: or just include jquery and put the code to set values of all href(s) to #, above your html code in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **domDocument**  to parse HTML and edit it:

```
<?php

    $html='<div id="olpDivId"> <span class="olpCondLink" ><a class="buyAction olpBlueLink" href="/gp/offer-listing/B002YDZSQM/ref=dp_olp_new/192-2317768-5155903?ie=UTF8&condition=new">4&nbsp;new</a>&nbsp;from&nbsp;<span class="price">$164.99</span></span> <span class="olpCondLink" ><a class="buyAction olpBlueLink" href="/gp/offer-listing/B002YDZSQM/ref=dp_olp_used/192-2317768-5155903?ie=UTF8&condition=used">18&nbsp;used</a>&nbsp;from&nbsp;<span class="price">$80.00</span></span> <span class="olpCondLink" ><a class="buyAction olpBlueLink" href="/gp/offer-listing/B002YDZSQM/ref=dp_olp_refurbished/192-2317768-5155903?ie=UTF8&condition=refurbished">6&nbsp;refurbished</a>&nbsp;from&nbsp;<span class="price">$124.95</span></span> </div>';
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML(  $html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach($links as $link){
        $link->setAttribute('href','#');
    }
    echo $dom->saveHTML();

?>
```

Comment: I get the following error Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity. On the following line:  $dom->loadHTML($doctype . $html);

Comment: that's because your html is **not** well-formatted!

Comment: for example you have **&condition** in your HTML which should be **&amp;condition**